# Understanding Dickey-Fuller test results on series with non-constant variance

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity, heteroscedasticity, augmented-dickey-fuller

My understanding is that a time series that does not appear to have constant variance over time is not stationary and that the [Dickey Fuller test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test) tests for stationarity (with the null hypothesis that the series is not stationary).

I created a synthetic series of 1000 points where each successive point is drawn from a Gaussian distribution with increasing variance. I ran the Dickey Fuller test on the series and consistently get significant p-values indicating the series is stationary. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the test or what a stationary series is.

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
result = []
np.random.seed(42)
for i in np.arange(0,10,0.001):
    result.append(np.random.normal(scale=i))
print(adfuller(result, autolag='AIC')[0])
print(adfuller(result, autolag='AIC')[4])
```

Output

```
-23.097799978008958
{'1%': -3.431005409094333, '5%': -2.8618296517685877, '10%': -2.566924176499291}
```

Comment: Hi @Yandle. Perhaps print the output? But for the time being, the null is "the series exhibits unit root"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null hypothesis of the augmented Dickey-Fuller test is not that the time series is nonstationary but that it contains a unit root. The time series you generated does not contain a unit root, so the ADF test predictably rejects $H_0$, just as it should.

Comment: The Wikipedia article seems to imply that unit root and non-stationary are synonymous "A unit root is present if $\rho =1$. The model would be non-stationary in this case.", is this incorrect?

Comment: @Yandle, *A implies not B* is not equivalent to *Not A implies B*. While you **cannot** have presence of a unit root (A) and stationarity (B) simultaneously (so A does imply not B), you **can** have absence of a unit root (not A) and absence of stationarity (not B) simulateneously (not A does not imply B).

Comment: So the alternative hypothesis is $\rho\neq 1$, not 'stationarity'?

Comment: @Yandle, the alternative hypothesis is $\rho<1$. There is also a version of the test where the alternative is $\rho>1$ (an explosive process) but it is less commonly applied.